# Is there a way to styling (e.g. fonts) when using widgetframe to embed a plotly chart in R?

Tags: css, r, plotly, hugo, htmlwidgets

I've created a chart in R using `plotly`, and I'm attempting to embed it in my Hugo blog.  I was unable to actually embed the chart until I found the `widgetframe` package (using the `framewidget()` function, however I now realized that `widgetframe` strips the font styling that I used within the chart (the chart looks fine on my computer, but if I look at the site from a machine where the font isn't installed, the font is reverted to Times New Roman).  Is there a way to keep custom styling while using `framewidget()`?

For reference, the font I'm using is Lekton, which can be found on Google Fonts.  I also use the font for the Hugo site itself, and it is displayed just fine on every other page of the site.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: So you are asking if you can embed a raster image of the output you are seeing?